# How to check for autocorrelation after a generalised estimating equation in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have run a number models using `xtgee` in Stata and am unsure of how to check for the presence of residual autocorrelation. The GEE is a logistic regression model for panel data (i.e. logit link and binomial family). There seem to be a number of user-written packages available (e.g. `xtqptest`, `xthrtest` and `xtistest`) but these don't work with `xtgee`, nor is it possible to use `predict varname, residuals` to obtain residuals and to inspect autocorrelation graphically.

I have attempted to calculate the residuals manually (i.e. `residuals = observed - predicted`) but these created non-sensical results.

How can I check for the presence of autocorrelation after using `xtgee`?

Example data & model:

```
webuse nlswork, clear
xtset idcode year
xtgee collgrad i.union, link(logit) fam(binomial) corr(exch) eform robust
```

Comment: I have read in a few different online forums that applying robust standard errors should resolve most heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation issues (particularly as I have large N), but I can't find a definitive journal or textbook reference. If anyone has a reference that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In GEE, the residuals are used for defining the correlation structure of the model.  The default structure employed will be exchangeable.  Otherwise, you might assess model fit using various correlation structures, such as

- exchangeable (default)
- independent
- unstructured
- fixed matname (user-specified)
- ar # (autoregressive of order #)
- stationary # (stationary of order #)
- nonstationary # (nonstationary of order #)

After each model is run, you can fetch the working covariance matrix using, e.g.:

```
estat wcorrelation
```

I always try to get the repeated measurement variables in wide format and then obtain the covariance matrix for all the outcome variables, using, e.g.:

```
corr collgrad1-collgrad10,cov
```

If there are any negative elements in the covariance matrix for repeated values in the e.g. `collgrad1-collgrad10` variables, the correlation structure will be `unstructured`, and XTGEE will most likely not converge and be very ill-conditioned (or unspecified).  For your interest in autocorrelation, however, try using

```
xtgee collgrad i.union, link(logit) fam(binomial) corr(ar1) eform robust
```

or

```
xtgee collgrad i.union, link(logit) fam(binomial) corr(ar2) eform robust
```